# How do I check if values in one array feature in a separate array, and then if they do, return those values after converting them each to new values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with ID numbers and a second array with names for those ID numbers.
I then have a third array that will only contain a few of the ID numbers.
What I want to do is check the values in the third array against the first array that contains all the IDs. Then the IDs that feature in both the first and third array I want to return as the matching names in the second array that has the names for the IDs in the first array.

```
let seriesIDs = [ 5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887 ];
let seriesNames = [ '9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX' ];
seriesIDs = seriesNames;

let thirdArray = [ 5869, 5865 ];
```

(these values won't be known beforehand. I will have the third array which I will loop through and check which values feature in the array named seriesIDs above)

I need to loop thirdArray and then the values in thirdArray I need to check against the array seriesIDs and the matching values in that array should trigger the return of the corresponding names in the array seriesNames.

so for example if thirdArray contains the values [ 5869, 5865 ] then what I would want returned would be '9XE' and '8XE'

Can anyone help?

Comment: As currently written your question shows no research effort. Have you tried to implement the requirement. What was the problem? Also please read  [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? And why are you setting `seriesIds = seriesNames`?

Comment: for starters, don't reassign seriesNames to seriesIds. You're losing your names data!

Comment: yes I did try various solution prior to asking the question but the code was not worth publishing as it was part of a big plugin and would have looked really confusing without all the other files which would have been too much, so I simplified what I was attempting to do into a format that would hopefully be easy for somebody to see a solution to, and they did. I now have my plugin working and I am extremely grateful to those who assisted. It's usually me helping others, I don't usually ask for help myself.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is switch from two arrays to one object. Let's say instead of:

```
let seriesIDs = [ 5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887 ];
let seriesNames = [ '9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX' ];
```

I'd do:

```
const seriesMap = {
    5862: '9XM',
    5869: '9XE',
    ...
    5887: '2NX'
};
```

Then you could simply check names by indexer operator:

```
const firstName = seriesMap[thirdArray[0]];
const secondName = seriesMap[thirdArray[1]];
```

Anyway if such solution is not possible for you. You can do it like this:

```
let seriesIDs = [ 5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887 ];
let seriesNames = [ '9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX' ];
let thirdArray = [ 5869, 5865 ]; 

const names = [];
for(const id of thirdArray) {
    const idx = seriesIDs.indexOf(id);
    if(idx !== -1) {
        names.push(seriesNames[idx]);
    }
}

console.log(names);
```

Comment: thank you so so much. honestly guys you have really saved my life with your help.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Please select one of the answers (the one that answers best your question), so it might help others faster :)

Answer (score 1):

A helpful first step is to create one array of pairs

- `[5862, '9XM']`
- `[5869, '9XE']`
- ⋮

from the two arrays. You can do that by mapping each element in one array to that pair according to its index, then make a function out of that operation and call it `zip`:

```
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((x, i) => [x, b[i]]);
```

An array of pairs is exactly what the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor wants:

```
const namesByID = new Map(zip(seriesIDs, seriesNames));
```

and that `Map` will let you look up names… by id. (Example: `namesByID.get(5887) === '2NX'`.)

From there, convert your array of ids to look up into an array of either names (id found in the map) or `undefined`s (what [`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) returns when the key doesn’t exist):

```
thirdArray.map(id => namesByID.get(id))
```

and take out the `undefined`s:

```
thirdArray
    .map(id => namesByID.get(id))
    .filter(name => name !== undefined)
```

```js
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((x, i) => [x, b[i]]);


const seriesIDs = [5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887];
const seriesNames = ['9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX'];

const namesByID = new Map(zip(seriesIDs, seriesNames));

const thirdArray = [5869, 5865];

console.log(
    thirdArray
        .map(id => namesByID.get(id))
        .filter(name => name !== undefined)
);
```

Comment: wow. you're truly amazing. thank you so much. and so quick to answer too. honestly you have no idea how much I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
seriesIDs.map((id, index) => thirdArray.includes(id) && seriesNames[index]).filter(item => item)
```

Comment: This would change resulting order unless `seriesIDs` array has the same ordering as `thirdArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object lookup using the `seriesIDs` and `seriesNames`, then using `array#map` get the series name for each series ID.

```js
let seriesIDs = [ 5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887 ],
    seriesNames = [ '9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX' ],
    thirdArray = [ 5869, 5865 ],
    lookup = Object.assign(...seriesIDs.map((v,i) => ({[v]: seriesNames[i]}))),
    result = thirdArray.map(v => lookup[v]);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining 2 arrays better you make array of an object.
i.e:

```
let serialIDs=[{id:5862, name:'9XM'},{id:5869, name:'9XE'},{id:5865, name:'8XE'},{id:5883, name:'8XT'},{id:5884, name:'8XEP'},{id:5887 , name:'2NX'}];
```

Then do filtering:

```
serialIDs.filter(function(item) {  return thirdArray.includes(item.id); });  // It will return filtered array
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's a solution

Keep names when the corresponding id is present

```js
const selectIDs = (seriesIDs, seriesNames, ids) =>
  seriesNames.filter((_, i) => ids.includes(seriesIDs[i]))
  
const seriesIDs = [ 5862, 5869, 5865, 5883, 5884, 5887 ];
const seriesNames = [ '9XM', '9XE', '8XE', '8XT', '8XEP', '2NX' ];
const thirdArray = [ 5869, 5865 ]

console.log(selectIDs(seriesIDs, seriesNames, thirdArray))
```

Comment: yes Chris. that it a really slick way of doing it. thank you for submitting, it's much appreciated.